# PHP code works on my localhost, but not on my webserver

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, I am currently programming a small script, everything is working fine so far on my localhost and also on the webserver.

Except one page, this completely blocks the INSERT INTO commands and the SELECT commands in the While loop.

The database is 1:1 like on my localhost.
There are also no error messages displayed, not even with:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

I really don't know anymore, on the server all other pages, queries, entries are working.

Only on this page not, where is my error?

```
session_start();
require_once('assets/include/header.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
function random_string() {
    if(function_exists('random_bytes')) {
        $bytes = random_bytes(16);
        $str = bin2hex($bytes);
    } else if(function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $str = bin2hex($bytes);
    } else if(function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
        $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $str = bin2hex($bytes);
    } else {
        //Bitte euer_geheim_string durch einen zufälligen String mit >12 Zeichen austauschen
        $str = md5(uniqid('euer_geheimer_string', true));
    }
    return $str;
}

//Überprüfe auf den 'Angemeldet bleiben'-Cookie
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) && isset($_COOKIE['identifier']) && isset($_COOKIE['securitytoken'])) {
    $identifier = $_COOKIE['identifier'];
    $securitytoken = $_COOKIE['securitytoken'];

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM securitytokens WHERE identifier = ?");
    $result = $statement->execute(array($identifier));
    $securitytoken_row = $statement->fetch();

    if(sha1($securitytoken) !== $securitytoken_row['securitytoken']) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    } else { //Token war korrekt
        //Setze neuen Token
        $neuer_securitytoken = random_string();
        $insert = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE securitytokens SET securitytoken = :securitytoken WHERE identifier = :identifier");
        $insert->execute(array('securitytoken' => sha1($neuer_securitytoken), 'identifier' => $identifier));
        setcookie("identifier",$identifier,time()+(3600*24*365)); //1 Jahr Gültigkeit
        setcookie("securitytoken",$neuer_securitytoken,time()+(3600*24*365)); //1 Jahr Gültigkeit

        //Logge den Benutzer ein
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $securitytoken_row['user_id'];
    }
}


if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$userid]);
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    extract($user);
}


if(isset($userid)){

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT vorname FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$userid]);
    $rowUser = $stmt->fetch();
    $username = $rowUser['vorname'];

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT coins FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$userid]);
        $coins = $stmt->fetch();
        extract($coins);
        $userCoins = $coins;
}

$page = $_GET['page'];


$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subthreads WHERE subThreadsID  = ?");
$stmt->execute([$page]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
extract($row);

$threadName = $row['threadName'];
$threadContent = $row['threadContent'];
$createdComments = $row['created_at'];
$dateNow = date_create($createdComments, timezone_open('Europe/Berlin'));
$timeNow = time();
$seconds = strtotime($createdComments);
$diffSeconds = $timeNow - $seconds;
$date = date_format($dateNow, 'd.m.Y - H:i');

if($diffSeconds < 60){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 1 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 300){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 5 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 600){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 10 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 900){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 15 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 1200){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 20 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 1500){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 25 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 1800){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 30 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 2100){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 35 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 2400){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 40 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 2700){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 45 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 3000){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 50 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 3300){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 55 Min.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 3600){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 1 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 7200){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 2 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 10800){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 3 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 14400){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 4 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 18000){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 5 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 21600){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 6 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 25200){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 7 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 28800){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 8 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 32400){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 9 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 36000){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 10 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 39600){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 11 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 43200){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 12 Std.";
} elseif($diffSeconds <= 86400){
    $diffSeconds = date_format($dateNow, 'H:i');
} elseif($diffSeconds > 86400){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 1 Tag";
} elseif($diffSeconds > 172800){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 2 Tage";
} elseif($diffSeconds > 259200){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 3 Tage";
} elseif($diffSeconds > 345600){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 4 Tage";
} elseif($diffSeconds > 432000){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 5 Tage";
}  elseif($diffSeconds > 518400){
    $diffSeconds = "Vor 5 Tage";
} else {
    $diffSeconds = date_format($dateNow, 'd.m.Y');
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT subThreadsID, threadsID FROM subthreads WHERE subThreadsID = ?");
$stmt->execute([$page]);
$rowName = $stmt->fetch();
$threadID = $rowName['threadsID'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, threadName FROM threads WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute([$threadID]);
$rowThreadName = $stmt->fetch();
$threadNameIndex = $rowThreadName['threadName'];

if(isset($_POST['addComment'])){
    $error = false;
    $comment = htmlentities($_POST['comment']);

    if(strlen($comment) == 0){
        $error = true;
    }

    if($comment == ""){
        $error = true;
    }

    if($error == false){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO subComments (subThreadsID, username, userid, threadContent) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->execute([$page, $username, $userid, $comment]);

    }

}

function random_chars($charNbr)
{
    $chars = array('default','primary','success','danger','warning');
    $randomchar = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$charNbr;++$i)
    {
        $randomchar .= $chars[rand(0,4)];
    }
    echo $randomchar;
}

?>
<div class="loadding-page">
    <div class="cssload-box-loading"></div>
</div>
<div class="main-home-area pb-0 mt-5">
    <a class="page-back" onclick="history.back()"><i class="ri-arrow-left-s-line"></i></a>
</div>
<body class='sc5'>
<div class="body-overlay" id="body-overlay"></div>
<div class="single-restuarent-area">
    <div class="single-page-details">
        <?php if(isset($msg)){echo $msg;} ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="bd-callout bd-callout-primary">
             <?php echo"<small style='font-size: 13px; color:color: rgb(120, 124, 126);'><b><a href='subthreads.php?page={$threadID}'>{$threadNameIndex} /</a> </b> gepostet von <a href='/userprofile.php?id={$row['userid']}'>{$row['username']}</a> · {$diffSeconds}</small>"; ?>
                <div class="threadName" style="font-size: 19px"><b><?php echo $threadName; ?></b><br></div>
                <div class="threadContent" style="font-size: 14px"><?php echo $threadContent; ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert" style="box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" row="3" style="font-size: 14px; height: 150px" placeholder="Was ist deine Meinung dazu...?" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="addComment" class="btn btn-primary w-100" style="font-size: 14px">Senf abgeben!</button>
    </form>
    </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subComments WHERE subThreadsID = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC");
    $stmt->execute([$page]);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $createdComments = $row['created_at'];
    $dateNow = date_create($createdComments, timezone_open('Europe/Berlin'));
    $timeNow = time();
    $seconds = strtotime($createdComments);
    $diffSeconds = $timeNow - $seconds;
    $date = date_format($dateNow, 'd.m.Y - H:i');

    if($diffSeconds < 60){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 1 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 300){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 5 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 600){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 10 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 900){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 15 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 1200){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 20 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 1500){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 25 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 1800){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 30 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 2100){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 35 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 2400){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 40 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 2700){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 45 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 3000){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 50 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 3300){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 55 Min.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 3600){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 1 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 7200){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 2 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 10800){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 3 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 14400){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 4 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 18000){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 5 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 21600){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 6 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 25200){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 7 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 28800){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 8 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 32400){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 9 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 36000){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 10 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 39600){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 11 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds <= 43200){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 12 Std.";
    } elseif($diffSeconds >= 46800){
        $diffSeconds = date_format($dateNow, 'H:i');
    } elseif($diffSeconds > 86400){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 1 Tag";
    } elseif($diffSeconds > 172800){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 2 Tage";
    } elseif($diffSeconds > 259200){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 3 Tage";
    } elseif($diffSeconds > 345600){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 4 Tage";
    } elseif($diffSeconds > 432000){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 5 Tage";
    }  elseif($diffSeconds > 518400){
        $diffSeconds = "Vor 5 Tage";
    } else {
        $diffSeconds = date_format($dateNow, 'd.m.Y');
    }

    echo'<div class="comments-list">';
    echo'<div class="media">';
    echo'<div class="media-body">'; ?>
            <div class="bd-callout bd-callout-<?php random_chars(1); ?>" style="font-size: 14px">
        <?php
        if(isset($userid)){
            echo"<div class='media-heading user_name'><a href='/userprofile.php?id={$row['userid']}'>{$row['username']}</a> · <small>{$diffSeconds}</a></small></div>";
        } else {
            echo"<div class='media-heading user_name'><a href='/login.php'>{$row['username']}</a> · <small>{$diffSeconds}</a></small></div>";
        }
        echo"{$row['threadContent']}";
        ?>
        <?php
        echo'</div>';
        echo'</div>';
        echo'</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
require_once('assets/include/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Turn MySQL error reporting on, too. Divide and conquer on this page. Put some `die` messages around with unique messages to see where things aren’t getting to that you expect them to.

Comment: Are you saying that the `while()` loop is not executing? That must be because the SQL statement is returning zero rows (or perhaps generating an error). I suggest you check the value of `$page`.

Comment: Why do you have this line of code `<body class='sc5'>` in the middle of `<div>` tags?